# Is Seq2Seq the right model for my data? Any examples?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, data-science, pytorch

I'm trying to train a model to predict design patterns from web pages. I'm using coordinates of bounding rects given a bunch of element groupings. Patterns look like this:

```
 [[elementId, width, height, x, y]]
```

so my target would be the `[[x,y]]` given `[[elementId, width, height]]`.

Concretely:

```
 [[5, 1.0, 1.0], [4, 1.0, 1.0], [2, 175.0, 65.0], [2, 1.0, 1.0], [4, 1.0, 1.0]]
 ->
 [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 10.0], [3.0, 0.0], [0.0, 68.0], [0.0, 10.0]]


 [[2, 14.0, 14.0], [2, 14.0, 14.0], [2, 14.0, 14.0]]  
 ->
 [[0.0, 3.0], [0.0, 3.0], [0.0, 3.0]]
```

Patterns vary in size so I've padded them with `[[0,0,0]]`. I currently have about 15k of them, but can get more.

I was told that seq2seq with attention is the right model for this job. I've started with https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-encoder-decoder-model-sequence-sequence-prediction-keras/ and achieved horrendous results.

Every seq2seq example i can find (searching for keras or pytorch) is used for translation which is categorical and I'm struggling to find a good regression based example.

So my questions are:

1. Is this the right model (encoder/decoder LSTM) for what i'm trying to do?
2. Is there any examples if so?

Comment: If your input and output size is fixed as it looks from the examples, you don't need a seq2seq model. You can use a simple feed-forward model with the appropriate loss. seq2seq/lstm etc are really for the purpose when sequence sizes (input/output) are variable

Comment: Umang, thank you for your response. I will try a simpler model. While i have you, any suggestions on activation/opt/loss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seq2Seq/LSTM are used when input/output are variable lengths.

Your input is of size 3 and output is of size 2 (at least for the given examples).  So you can use a simple one/two-hidden layer feed-forward model with the L2/L1 loss (for regression). Any opt (SGD/Adam) should be fine, however, Adam works well in practice.

Also, I think you should not use coordinates as it is, you can scale it so that the highest coordinate is 1 and hence the input/output range would be between 0 and 1. An added advantage, this would help you to generalize to different screen sizes intuitively.